# Losing performance when switching order of operations in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to put a softmax layer on the final output of an RNN. However, not all my sequences are the same length, so I am using tf.gather() to collect the final outputs of the RNN. For some reason, I have to do this *after* I apply the matrix multiplication for the softmax like so:

```
rnn_output = make_rnn_output()
outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_output, (-1, self._num_units))

indices = (tf.range(self._batch_size) *
               self._max_steps + self._sequence_length - 1)
softmax_w = tf.get_variable('softmax_w', (self._num_units, self._output_size))
softmax_b = tf.get_variable('softmax_b', self._output_size)
logits = tf.matmul(outputs, softmax_w) + softmax_b
final_logits = tf.gather(indices)
# blah blah
```

If I move the gather call to before the matmul call, I get significantly lower accuracy. I do not see why this is the case, as it should make no difference. I would like to move the gather call before the matmul call to reduce the unnecessary operations being done in the matmul.

Comment: This is really weird. The order in which you build your graph nodes should almost not matter in terms of when they get executed.

Comment: Just to be clear I didn't just want to reorder, I wanted to apply the gather to the outputs, and then multiply the filtered output by softmax_w, as opposed to multiplying the full output by softmax_w, then filtering.